# Sum of a list 2 elements by 2 elements

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a 25 elements list like

```
tab=[6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5]
```

And I want to create a new list tab1 which display the sum of the elements of the list two by two, if the list is odd I don't have to calculate the sum on the last element.
And it has to be done with a for loop for... any ideas?
Any help would be appreciated.
I tried on my side but without success.

i tried this :

```
for i in tab:
print(sum(i:len(tab))
```

it gives me a syntax error and i tried some of others things but didn't work...

i tried this too

```
for i in tab:
print(sum(i,i+1))
```

didn't work too

and when i do this

```
sum=0
for i in tab:
print(sum(tab[i]+tab[i+1]))
```

it gives me back : TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: "I tried on my side but without success.": it is generally appreciated if you actually show what you tried, and how it failed (what did you expect, and what did you get)? That way, we can point to a mistake you may have made, instead of just giving you the answer.

Comment: Syntax Error means you mistyped something in your code. It's the easiest to fix

Comment: i updated my code and errors

Comment: Indentations in Python are meaningful.

Comment: @AspiringPhysicist This is a syntax error because your for loop is empty; you probably forgot to indent the print statement

Comment: You still haven't shown us the result you expect for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the list with steps of 2.

```py
orig_len = len(tab)  # List length
tab1 = []
for i in range(0, orig_len - orig_len%2, 2):
  tab1.append(tab[i] + tab[i+1])
print(tab1)
```

You have to round down the number to first smaller even number, which is that `orig_len - orig_len%2` does.

Comment: it works perfectly...I had no idea to use the range! thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```python
tab=[6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5]
print([sum(tab[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(tab),2)])
```

The output will be:

```python
[11, 11, 6, 5, 7, 9, 6, 11, 6, 4, 2, 5, 5]
```

Comment: thanks you a lot...it works perfectly there

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved by:

```
tab = [6, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5]
tab1 = []
initial_pos = 0

for i in range(2, len(tab), 2):
    tab1.append(sum(tab[initial_pos:i]))
    initial_pos = I

    if i == len(tab) - 2:
        tab1.append(sum(tab[i:]))
```

What is happening here is we are iterating through `tab` starting at the third element and summing the values of elements of the slice `tab[0:2]`, then `initial_pos` will assume the value of 2 and I the value of 4, so in the next iteration we will be appending `sum(tab[2:4])`to tab1 and so forth.

The if statement makes sure this works for odd lists and even lists.